# Google Maps API V3 : Great results, then poor ones after 27th April

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have an application which has been running the Google Maps API v.3 for around 6 weeks now, previously we were working with v.2.

Our application lists 15 random results on the home page, and was doing this beautifully. But then on the 17th April, 2012; we were only able to get limited results (no more then 9).

Here's the URL: [www.searchsearch.com](http://www.searchsearch.com)

Were there any updates that may have affected our source code around that date, which is "restricting" our calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You request the placeDetails, (for me there are 18 places), but there is a general limit for all Maps-Webservices (10 request per second), so you will only get 10 responses.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/faq#js_usage_limits

You may use a timeout after each 10 places to get more details.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i will try and request the API and second time round to get 15 results not 10.